# If A and B are two given vectors and what is the procedure to find A.▽B and A x ▽B at a given point?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, inner-products, cross-product

This is what I did:

1. Calculated ▽B and substituted the value of the point to find a vector
2. Calculated **A** at the given point by substituted the coordinates in the vector
3. Dot product of the two to find a vector (final ans)

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 1)-3), and 4) Calculate vector product to find $\bf{A}\times\nabla\bf{B}$.

Comment: oops right that too, thank you!